# jQuery.DomOutline formation issue on selected area

Tags: google-chrome-extension, document-body

I want to create a chrome extension that let the user to select html element like firebug and i've implemented it with a jQuery plugin called [jQuery.DomOutline](https://github.com/andrewchilds/jQuery.DomOutline).

The problem is that it whenever I select an element in a web page that has

```
margin:0 auto
```

and fixed width on it's `body` tag, it shows an ill formatted selected area.

Comment: Try a different outliner like uBlock's https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/blob/master/src/js/scriptlets/element-picker.js

Comment: @wOxxOm Is there any demo link?

Comment: It's part of the extension, you can install it, the picker icon is inside the popup.